# responseText of AJAX Request using php is empty

Tags: php, ajax, responsetext

I am quite a noob to AJAX Requesting and PHP and I got a question:
I am trying to do a GET request to a php file on my wamp server but it's responseText stays blank and when I check the status code when the readyState is 4, it's 0.

When I execute the php file in the browser it returns my expectation: An array with JSON Objects.

Does anyone know the answer?

Javascript code:

```
this.getCars = function(id) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var that = this;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.status);
            //that.lastTableCars = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/getCars.php?q="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("autobay", $con);

$sql= "SELECT * FROM autoos WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$info = [];
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $info[] = $row; 
}

echo json_encode($info);

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Your php code is missing the `?>`...

Comment: Your code is sql injection vulnerable and deprecated(mysql)

Comment: `?>` is not required .

Comment: Might I suggest using jQuery for your ajax calls.  I'm so unfamiliar with the plain javascript way to do it as this point that it's hard to see if anything is wrong.  jQuery makes it a lot easier (in my opinion) and might solve your problem.

Comment: This is not for website purposes, its for an assignment for school and thus is only used locally. @BlargleMonster Using JQuery is an option, but shouldn't be needed. We as students will be rewarded by not using it

Comment: @thejh it might be on purpose http://activeblogging.com/info/can-you-leave-off-the-closing-php-tag-in-your-source-code/

Comment: @Serf If I may, I strongly suggest you check out the PHP chat room here in StackOverflow and ask them what you can do about your-sever side code. It uses deprecated mysql_* functions and string concatenated queries, both of which are bad ideas. As for your client side code, I strongly agree with you on using vanilla JavaScript before using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, use jQuery to help troubleshoot. It's going to make your life so much easier. Even if you end up wanting to use raw xmlhttprequest, I'd suggest bringing jQuery in to rule out xmlhttprequest problems in your code, and more quickly hone in on the real issue.

*Translation: I'm not comfortable with raw xmlhttprequest, so in order to help you let's switch to jQuery. You can go back when the issue is resolved! =)*

```
this.getCars = function(id) {
   $.get("/getCars.php?q="+id, function(data) {
      alert("response from server: " + data);
   });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Also make sure you are using Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to inspect the response from your server, it's possible that it's failing there.

**Update:**

Make sure your HTML page (that is making the ajax call) and the PHP script are running on the same domain (localhost). I noticed you were specifying the full `http://localhost` URL in your ajax call. Ajax does not work cross-domain (though there are workarounds, look at JSONP if you really need to do this cross-domain). Best bet is to get your HTML page loading from the same domain as the PHP script.

**Update 2:**

Actual issue was that the OP was loading the HTML from a folder on his computer (not via `http://localhost`) and trying to make an ajax call to `http://localhost`. The ajax call was failing since this is technically cross domain.

Comment: Used it, same result, blank response (data), also Firebug indicates the ajax request with a red color

Comment: If Firebug is showing a red color, that usually means that the server failed to return a valid response. Like a 500 server error. You should be able to inspect the ajax call in Firebug and see exactly what is coming back from the server. Perhaps you aren't passing in a valid ID, and your database query is failing?

Comment: Database query is not failing because when I run the php file directly on the server it returns the data I want

Comment: Yeah but when you run the php file directly on the server YOU are passing in ?id=X yourself. When you test ajax, your getCars(id) method might not be getting a valid ID, and isn't passing a valid ID to the server. Bottom line: use firebug to inspect exactly what you're sending to the server. Without that you're shooting in the dark.

Comment: So then Net tab, click on the ajax call that was just sent, and then the Response tab. That'll show what the server is sending back. You seeing valid JSON in your response?

Comment: the response is blank, that's my problem I am having and so asking a question about

Comment: Then it's a problem on the server, not ajax. In the Net tab right-click on the ajax url and select "open in new tab" to open the exact URL directly. I don't think it's the same as when you test manually, something is different.

Comment: When I do that you just said a page opens up with the information I want (Array with json objects)

Comment: Are you running the HTML page on http://localhost? I noticed you are specifying the full http://localhost/ domain in the ajax call. Can that be changed to just /getCars.php, or does it need the full URL?

Comment: The HTML Page is somewhere else on my computer but when I put all the stuff in the www folder it still needs localhost in front

Comment: That's it! See my updated response. Ajax doesn't work cross domain, you need both the HTML page and the PHP script loading from the same domain.

Comment: I have done what you said, still doesn't fix my problem, empty response

Comment: Yes. Only a page running from localhost can make ajax calls to another localhost url.

Comment: @jszobody Please update your answer to reflect your conversation with Serf. As it currently stands your answer (use jQuery) did not solve the problem. Answering questions with 'use jQuery' is generally regarded as bad etiquette on stack overflow (google 'when it is appropriate to answer 'use jQuery' meta stackoverflow')

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did update the answer. See the "Update:" part of my answer, that dealt with the real issue. I can go edit out the jquery part if that's best? I recommended jquery as a way to troubleshoot, rule out xmlhttprequest issues, and hone in on the real problem.